# Why when thread starts, the form crashes?Is Thread-safe?

Tags: c#, forms, thread-safety, label

I've a game with 90 grey numbers and, periodically, some of them become blue.(Simplified!)

Now i use:
Game-->Timer-->Thread-->coloring numbers
because i want use my game also when the numbers in coloration.

the code:

```
some variables..
public FormHome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TEstrazione = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        TEstrazione.AutoReset = false;
        TEstrazione.Elapsed += timerEstrazioneElapsed;
        TEstrazione.Start();
    }
private void timerEstrazioneElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadEstrazione = new Thread(cThread);
            ThreadEstrazione.IsBackground = true;
            ThreadEstrazione.Start();
        }
 private void cThread()
        {          
//other methods that change others controls..   
                coloring();    
                TEstrazione.Start();
            }
 void coloring()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)//20 numbers to make colored
            {
                int num = *get random number*;
                Label lbl;
                lbl = (Label)panelNumembers.Controls["n" + num.ToString()];

            if (lbl.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lbl.Invoke(new Action(coloring), new object[] { });
                return;
            }

            lbl.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
            lbl.ForeColor = Color.Navy;
            lbl.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep(800);
        }
    }
```

*excuse me if some names are in italian but i think they aren't important.*
The problem is that when the thread is coloring the label, the program locks: i can't push buttons and even close it!
 **I think is a thread-safe problem but i don't know other ways.**

As i've written, there are other methods inside a cThread, all change the controls. One of theese is:

```
void refreshLabel()
                { 
//here I always used one of the controls for the InvokeRequired
     because in some cases I have so many and if I do the InvokeRequired 
    for each control becomes too long the code
                    if (label1.InvokeRequired) 
                    {
                        ne.Invoke(new Action(refreshLabel), new object[] { });
                        return;
                    }           
             label1.Text = "xxxxx"; 
             label1.Refresh();
             label2.Text = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";      
             label2.Refresh();
                }
```

**In conclusion I have a lot of methods started by cThread that change a lot of controls, there is a way to make it thread safe without stretching too much code?**
I apologize for the English but I'm Italian and is not easy explain the problems in an another language.

Comment: You cant modify UI elements from a background thread.

Comment: why? In this way I modify the UI but it meanwhile lock

Comment: What do you think that recursive call you enter if `InvokeRequired` is true does?

Comment: There is minor difference between `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`...

Comment: @Leonardo Rignanese seems that the method coloring() invoke into the UI thread with a sleep of 800 ms therefore your UI freezes (the sleep execute 20 time 800x20 = 16sec of blocking)

Comment: @OldFox yes, the UI blocks for 16sec! How can i use it at the same time? BeginInvoke not works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using my girlfriend laptop so I'll edit my answer and give you a much better answer ASAP. the problem occurred because most of the execution is in the UI thread. you should execute most of your execution in background. when you want to update the UI you need to change context to the UI thread(only updates!).

Change coloring to:

```
void coloring()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)//20 numbers to make colored
    {
        int num = *get random number*;
        Label lbl;
        lbl = (Label)panelNumembers.Controls["n" + num.ToString()];

    var updateUI = new Action(() => {

    lbl.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
    lbl.ForeColor = Color.Navy;
    lbl.Refresh();
    });

    if (lbl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(updateUI);
    }
    else
    {
        updateUI();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(800);
}
```

if there is no other blocking operations inside your code then this might work

Comment: Ok, now works! Thanks! How have i to do if i want change more of one control? Can i add in updateUI other label for example?

Comment: you can update other labels inside updateUI, I don't recommend you to do this, because the code I gave you is a patch. to get a responsive UI you have to put most of your logic in the background. only UI updates should be at the UI thread. in my answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528767/why-when-thread-starts-the-form-crashesis-thread-safe/28550288#28550288) (he had similar problem to you) I attached a link to explanation about Invoke, I recommend you to read the link and then you'll understand everything.

Comment: Ps, I saw you wrote that you are new SD, so I recommends you to read the following books:(those books will help you in the future)
[C# via CLR](http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454) and/or  [C# in Depth](http://www.amazon.com/Depth-3rd-Edition-Jon-Skeet/dp/161729134X)

Comment: [agile principles and practices c#](http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Principles-Patterns-Practices-C/dp/0131857258/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424301337&sr=1-1&keywords=agile+principles+and+practices+c%23)  [clean code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y)  [The art of unit testing](http://www.amazon.com/Art-Unit-Testing-examples/dp/1617290890/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424301413&sr=1-1&keywords=The+art+of+unit+testing). wish you luck, OldFox